# Java - Generic Drools rule

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

I would like to create my rule more Generic format which mean it should be validate the fields and values. Following my POJO structure.

```
 public class RulesModel
private String field;
private List<String> values;
// other stuff
```

And my rule

```
rule "sample"
when
    $rule : RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook", values contains "youtube", value not contains "instagram" )  
then
    // actions
end
```

It's working fine to validate single field, but i want to validate the multiple fields of RulesModel. 
So i desire to create the POJO

```
public class RulesModelList {

    private List<RulesModel> ruleList;
    // Getter & Setter
}
```

So now when i pass the list of RulesModel by using RulesModelList class the rule should be validate like below

```
$rule : RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook") && $rule : RulesModel( field == "createdBy", values contains "admin")
```

How to validate that in Drools?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is verify that those two (or three or however many) RulesModels are in the list, it's quite simple:

```
// Example from question
rule "Verify Facebook source and admin createdBy"
when
  RulesModelList( $list: ruleList)
  exists(RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook") from $list)
  exists(RulesModel( field == "createdBy", values contains "admin") from $list)
then
  // do something
end
```

Basically I get the list of RulesModel out of the RulesModelList input and assign to `$list`. Then I verify that there exists a RulesModel instance that matches my 'source' criteria, and then one that matches the 'createdBy' criteria.

In the example I used `exists()` instead of assigning a variable because my sample rule doesn't need to make use of the RulesModel instance on the right hand side. If you *do* need to do something with the RulesModel instance, simply replace `exists()` with an assignment like this:

```
$source: RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook") from $list
$createdBy: RulesModel( field == "createdBy", values contains "admin") from $list
```

There is no need to do an accumulate unless you're trying to iterate over the list and find things that match a certain criteria. For example, let's say that one of the "field" values is "updatedBy", and there can be multiple RulesModel instances with that field name. To get the subset of the RulesModel instances with field name "updatedBy", you'd use accumulate, as Mykhaylo demonstrated in his answer.

But if all you want to do is verify that a list contains an object that meets your criteria, accumulate is overkill and this here is the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use java methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072844/drools-imports-java-static-method) in when block, for example [CollectionUtils.intersection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/commons_collections/commons_collections_intersection.htm)

```
import static org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils.intersection;
...
$rule : RulesModel( field == "source", !intersection(values, valuesToCheck).isEmpty())
```

Comment: i would compare list of RuleModel objects in a single time.  `$rule : RulesModel( field == "source", values contains "facebook") && $rule2 : RulesModel( field == "createdBy", values contains "admin") && $rule3 : RulesModel( field == "priority", values > 10)`

Comment: To validate multiple fields, you don't need collection of models. If you have collection of models and you want to find desired ones, this is totally different requirement and approach. You can use [forAll and accumulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182500/drools-collect-list-from-object-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze collection of elements using [forAll and accumulate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54182500/drools-collect-list-from-object-property)

```
RulesModelList($ruleList: ruleList)
$matchingList: List() from accumulate (
    $model: RulesModel(field == "source", values contains "facebook", values contains "youtube", value not contains "instagram") from $ruleList,
    accumulateList($model)
)
```